# Weird wording in our FAQ

Tags: word-choice, writing-style

This is completely minor, but it caught my eye in the [signature](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) section:

> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed.

Maybe it's me, but the "or" feels redundant in there. It feels like "as", "because", `.`  or   `;` would be better.

*(Asking this here as opposed to meta, because it is about word choice)*

Comment: I think it's clear enough, but to me it does feel slightly strange to say "Please... or". "Please... as" also sounds wrong -- you're not saying "don't use them because they will be removed" you're saying "they'll be removed because you shouldn't use them." But a full stop or an ". If you do" sounds fine.

Comment: I had a different question about this one. Does *they* refer to the posts, or the signatures?

Comment: @PeteroftheCorn: To the signatures.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's here worded as a simple warning, as a short form synonymous to “or else”:

> **or else**
>   • used to warn what will happen if something is not carried out: *you go along with this or else you're going to jail*.

<sup>(*New Oxford American Dictionary*)</sup>

Comment: +1 I agree. Even if maybe I would have used a different wording, it sounds like a legit choice.

Comment: I think that's _exactly_ why it seems a little funny to me. It's like saying, "Please don't be a bother, or else we will punish you by, um, cleaning up after you."

Answer (score 4):

I actually agree that the second 'or' seems a bit awkward.  As you said, I would say 'as' instead (indicating the consequence of the prohibited action), or a semicolon:

> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts; they will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

That wording is common usage, however I think it's awkward. Changing *or* to *as* would work well, or the *or* could be dropped entirely and the comma replaced with a semicolon.

> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts; they will be removed.
>
> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts as they will be just be removed.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with this sentence, and "or" is not being redundant. It has a different meaning as opposed to the earlier "or", and is necessary. Its meaning is "otherwise", that is :

> Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts, otherwise they will be removed.

There's nothing wrong with this sentence (repeated ad lib.)

Comment: Hm, maybe it's the repetition of 'or' that bothered me.

Comment: Well, if repetition was a problem, then this sentence does actually have a problem.... but repetition, unless on a great scale, is not poor sentence structuring